# Motherboard LED Debug Code without CPU or RAM?

Tags: hardware-failure, troubleshooting, debug, post

I'm trying to figure out which is faulty, my motherboard, CPU, or RAM. When I hit the power button, the power supply fan spins for a couple seconds but I get no other sign of life. Is my motherboard, the Asrock Z97 Extreme4, supposed to give LED debug codes if CPU and RAM are not installed? The manual has codes in it for a faulty CPU or missing RAM, but doesn't say whether it gives a code with no CPU.

Comment: Take out all the RAM. If it beeps, it knows there's no RAM. If you put the RAM back in, and it doesn't do anything, you have a VERY faulty RAM stick. It's also possible your powersupply isn't supplying the required voltage, so swap it out with a known working power supply to test if you can

Comment: Alright, the internal speaker is arriving in the mail today. I checked all the power supply voltages, and tested it in another computer, and it's fine.

Comment: You didn't even have an internal speaker yet? NICE! It's possible the LED debug codes are displaying something - but the LED's themselves could be bust. I don't know what those motherboards do if the LEDs go bust...

Comment: Installed the internal speaker, now the motherboard isn't signalling the power supply to power on. I tested that both the supply and button still work, but something in between isn't relaying the signal.

Comment: possibly a dead mobo... there might be some broken traces that are overlapping or interfering on the internal speaker circuit

Answer (score 1):

No code will be generated without CPU.

With CPU, if you do not have any RAM modules installed, you will hear beeps (1 long, then 3 short aka _ . . . ).

Some modern MBs have visual systems/indicators which provide additional info and those may be able to also indicate a missing or faulty CPU.

Comment: A code can be generated without the CPU, but it depends on the motherboard. Some motherboards can, some motherboards can't

Comment: I said that in the answer. Code yes, not beep code. I did not yet find a MB that can beep without CPU.

Comment: Some of the Dell Integrated Systems do... I've encountered it in my workplace before.